# max-entries=-1 is not accepted for overridden cache

Tags: infinispan, wildfly-10, second-level-cache

I have below configuration in `standalone.xml`. The custom cache named `data-local-query` defines the `max-entries="-1"` which is valid as per documentation to have unlimited entries.
But it seems there is a conflict with default `local cache` and hence WildFly has startup error.

Why cannot I define `max-entries="-1"` to override default one ?

**error**

```
Eviction maxEntries value cannot be less than or equal to zero if eviction is enabled
```

**standalone.xml**

```
<cache-container name="hibernate" default-cache="local-query" module="org.hibernate.infinispan">
            <local-cache name="entity">
                <transaction mode="NON_XA"/>
                <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
            </local-cache>
            <local-cache name="local-query">
                <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
            </local-cache>
             <local-cache name="data-local-query">
                <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="-1"/>
                <expiration max-idle="14400" interval="20000" lifespan="86400000"/>
            </local-cache>
            <local-cache name="timestamps"/>
        </cache-container>
```

**log error**

```
2017-04-19 18:00:27,215 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.infinispan.hibernate.data-local-query.config: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.infinispan.hibernate.data-local-query.config: org.infinispan.commons.CacheConfigurationException: Eviction maxEntries value cannot be less than or equal to zero if eviction is enabled
Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheConfigurationException: Eviction maxEntries value cannot be less than or equal to zero if eviction is enabled
        at org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder.validate(EvictionConfigurationBuilder.java:108)
        at org.infinispan.configuration.cache.ConfigurationBuilder.validate(ConfigurationBuilder.java:203)
        at org.infinispan.configuration.cache.ConfigurationBuilder.build(ConfigurationBuilder.java:246)
        at org.infinispan.configuration.cache.ConfigurationBuilder.build(ConfigurationBuilder.java:236)
        at org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.spi.service.ConfigurationBuilder.start(ConfigurationBuilder.java:79)
        at org.wildfly.clustering.service.AsynchronousServiceBuilder$1.run(AsynchronousServiceBuilder.java:102)
```

Comment: have you tried to set eviction strategy=NONE?

Comment: Ok I see the eviction with `maxentries=-1` eventually means no eviction at all. Thanks.